# How do I convert my recursive algorithm to an explicit formula?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I have the recursive formula:
\begin{align}
x_1&=1-\frac{1}{e} \\
x_{n+1}&=1-(1-x_n)^{1/x_n}
\end{align}
Is there any way to write this as an explicit formula? I've tried writing the exact forms of the first few terms but they get complicated very quickly and I can't see a pattern. I'm pretty sure it approaches $1$. Anyone know how to convert it, if it's even possible?

Some people have pointed out that this may be an XY problem, and you may be right. I'm essentially trying to find out two things about this equation:
a) is this function increasing (and does it approach 1)?
b) If it is increasing, at what n does x<sub>n</sub> pass a certain value (e.g., 0.9)

I thought converting to a function f(x) would be the easiest way to do this as I could then just plug in values and use a limit to find the answers I want, but I think I'm wrong about that, so any other ideas would be great.

This is essentially a probability equation I've set up with probability of an event x<sub>n</sub> changing for each n, so if the function is increasing it should approach one, although proving this would be nice too.

Comment: It might be helpful to add some motivation about why this question is likely to be relevant to others and the context in which you encountered this, and why you need an explicit formula.

Comment: In particular, I wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  Most likely there is no nice explicit formula.  That raises the question of what problem you're *actually* trying to solve, and whether there is some other way to accomplish it without having an explicit formula.

Comment: Ussually you sum both sides, in left you have $\sum x_i$ from $i=1$ to $i=n$, on right you have the same sum but from $i=1$ to $i=n-1$, so you can cancel both sides and have only $x_n$ on the left and the explicit formula in the right. But since your formula uses exponents you should try something different than "sum"

Comment: There are two aspects of your query, me think, i) the formula $f(x)$ you ask for, and ii) the numeric value for $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)$. Well, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ is known to be $e$, while for $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-1/n)^n$ "my" CAS returns $1/e$, thus your guess $1$ is somehow close and somehow it is not. This for ii), remains i) to solve.

Comment: Do you mean this instead?  $1 - X_n = (1 - X_{n-1})^{\frac{1}{X_{n-1}}}$

Comment: Oops -- I overlooked that $x_1 \ne 1$, so... sorry, my result for i) is wrong.

Comment: Even the limit does not have closed-form formula, then it's almost impossible that the sequence has closed-form formula.